# InApp Purchase not working in iPhone 5 device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, iphone-5

I have implemented In-App Purchase in my app. It is working well on iPhone 4 device, for both iOS5 and iOS6, but is not working on iPhone 5 device.

For iPhone 5, when I click In-App Purchase, the alert to buy the product pops up but is not asking for user id and password.

Any idea about which is the problem? Any help will be appreciated.

thanks..

Answer (score 4):

In iPhone 5, if you are already logged in your iTunes account with your test user account then It won't ask for password.

To disable this feature:
Settings->general->restrictions

And set "require password" to "immediately", it'll ask you for password.

It might help, if not then let me know.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Answer (score 1):

may be in your iPhone 5, you have already mentioned your apple id, for some other purchase through appstore.

you can goto settings and logout your apple id.
I think, you should get the pop up then. :)

Comment: thanks for reply. I have already tried it. But still it does not work.

Comment: if there is no apple id, and it is not asking for one, then how does your in app purchase proceed? are you getting a purchase notification? or transaction record, anything?